# Capture contents inside curly braces

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, text

So, as part of my application, I need it to read data from a text file, and get elements between curly brackets.

e.g:

```
Server_1 {

    /directory1 /directory2

}

Server_2 {

    /directory1

    /directory2

}
```

Then something like, if `Server == Server_1`, print the directories.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
\{(.*?)\}
```

[Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/axprkZ/1)

1. `\{ matches the character { literally (case sensitive)`
2. `(.*?) 1st Capturing Group`
3. `.*?` matches any character
4. `*?` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
5. `\}` matches the character `}` literally (case sensitive)

Sample Code to extract content inside curly bracket:

```
 import re

regex = r"\{(.*?)\}"

test_str = ("Server_1 {\n"
    "/directory1 /directory2\n\n"
    "}\n"
    "Server_2 {\n\n"
    "/directory1\n\n"
    "/directory2\n\n"
    "}")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        print (match.group(1))
```

[Run the code here](https://repl.it/EgJt/0)

Comment: thakns for the detailed explanation. regex go cryptic really quick.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to extract the server name, you can try with this:

```
fullConfig = """
Server_1 {
  /directory1 /directory2
}

Server_2  {
  /directory1
  /directory2
}
"""

# OUTPUT
# ('Server_1', '/directory1 /directory2\n')
# ('Server_2', '/directory1\n  /directory2\n')
regex = r'(\w+)\s*[^{]*{\s*([^}]+)\s*}'
for serverName, serverConfig in re.findall(regex, fullConfig):
  print(serverName, serverConfig)
```